# Return Pandas entry in specific format?

Tags: python, pandas

Right now, I'm searching through a pandas dataframe for entries that match a certain username. It's returning stuff like this:
`{"username":{"0":"user","1":"user","2":"user"},"title":{"0":"Title","1":"asdfasdfasdf","2":"Bob"},"start":{"0":"2020-07-10","1":"2020-07-25","2":"2020-07-10"},"end":{"0":"2020-08-01","1":"2020-07-25","2":"2020-07-11"},"startTime":{"0":"2020-07-25T14:24","1":"2020-07-25T14:25","2":"2020-07-25T19:29"},"endTime":{"0":"2020-07-31T14:24","1":"2020-07-25T14:25","2":"2020-07-25T14:32"},"color":{"0":"#000000","1":"#000000","2":"#ff0000"}}`

Is there a way to return values from the pandas dataframe in another format, such as this?
`{username: user, Title: asdsdfs, startTime: 2020-07-25T14:24}, {username: user, Title: asdsdfs, startTime: 2020-07-25T14:24}`
Sorry if this is a really obvious question, I'm doing this for a school related activity and I need the output in this format for another program of ours to work.

Comment: Can you share df.head().to_dict() and the code you are using to search the df?

Comment: Sure;
Here is df.head().to_dict()

Comment: {'username': {0: 'user', 1: 'user', 2: 'user', 3: 'user', 4: 'user'}, 'title': {0: 'Title', 1: 'asdfasdfasdf', 2: 'Bob', 3: 'fdfdfdfdfd', 4: 'asdfasdfsadf'}, 'start': {0: '2020-07-10', 1: '2020-07-25', 2: '2020-07-10', 3: '2020-07-02', 4: '2020-07-25'}, 'end': {0: '2020-08-01', 1: '2020-07-25', 2: '2020-07-11', 3: '2020-07-15', 4: '2020-07-26'}, 'startTime': {0: '2020-07-25T14:24', 1: '2020-07-25T14:25', 2: '2020-07-25T19:29', 3: '2020-07-25T14:33', 4: '2020-07-25T14:41'}, 'endTime': {0: '2020-07-31T14:24', 1: '2020-07-25T14:25', 2: '2020-07-25T14:32', 3: '2020-07-25T19:33', 4: '2020-07-25T14:

Comment: And the code I am using to search the df is 
`return self.user_df.loc[self.user_df['username'] == username, :]`

Comment: a bit more lines of code would be helpful... but so far that line seems to return a DataFrame, not a dictionary... and what you posted in your question is df.to_dict()... try: `df = {key: list(vals.values()) for key, vals in df.items()}`

Comment: which gives me `{'username': ['user', 'user', 'user'], 'title': ['Title', 'asdfasdfasdf', 'Bob'], 'start': ['2020-07-10', '2020-07-25', '2020-07-10'], 'end': ['2020-08-01', '2020-07-25', '2020-07-11'], 'startTime': ['2020-07-25T14:24', '2020-07-25T14:25', '2020-07-25T19:29'], 'endTime': ['2020-07-31T14:24', '2020-07-25T14:25', '2020-07-25T14:32'], 'color': ['#000000', '#000000', '#ff0000']}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {"username":{"0":"user","1":"user","2":"user"},
     "title":{"0":"Title","1":"asdfasdfasdf","2":"Bob"},
     "start":{"0":"2020-07-10","1":"2020-07-25","2":"2020-07-10"},
     "end":{"0":"2020-08-01","1":"2020-07-25","2":"2020-07-11"},
     "startTime":{"0":"2020-07-25T14:24","1":"2020-07-25T14:25","2":"2020-07-25T19:29"},
     "endTime":{"0":"2020-07-31T14:24","1":"2020-07-25T14:25","2":"2020-07-25T14:32"},
     "color":{"0":"#000000","1":"#000000","2":"#ff0000"}}

c = [{k:v for k,v in zip(d,i)} for i in zip(*[d[a].values() for a in d])]

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[{'username': 'user', 'title': 'Title', 'start': '2020-07-10', 'end': '2020-08-01', 'startTime': '2020-07-25T14:24', 'endTime': '2020-07-31T14:24', 'color': '#000000'},
 {'username': 'user', 'title': 'asdfasdfasdf', 'start': '2020-07-25', 'end': '2020-07-25', 'startTime': '2020-07-25T14:25', 'endTime': '2020-07-25T14:25', 'color': '#000000'},
 {'username': 'user', 'title': 'Bob', 'start': '2020-07-10', 'end': '2020-07-11', 'startTime': '2020-07-25T19:29', 'endTime': '2020-07-25T14:32', 'color': '#ff0000'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame(d).to_dict(orient='records')
print(d)

[{'username': 'user',
  'title': 'Title',
  'start': '2020-07-10',
  'end': '2020-08-01',
  'startTime': '2020-07-25T14:24',
  'endTime': '2020-07-31T14:24',
  'color': '#000000'},
 {'username': 'user',
  'title': 'asdfasdfasdf',
  'start': '2020-07-25',
  'end': '2020-07-25',
  'startTime': '2020-07-25T14:25',
  'endTime': '2020-07-25T14:25',
  'color': '#000000'},
 {'username': 'user',
  'title': 'Bob',
  'start': '2020-07-10',
  'end': '2020-07-11',
  'startTime': '2020-07-25T19:29',
  'endTime': '2020-07-25T14:32',
  'color': '#ff0000'}]
```